# How to mount a directory from container to the host in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have a payara server image which I am trying to run and mount server log from container to the host.

I run a container using this Dockerfile using the command below.

```
docker container run --name credit-card -p 4848:4848 -p 8080:8080 -v /home/osboxes/Docker/var/log/card/credit-card:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/production/logs credit-card
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM payara/server-full
ADD credit-card-3.0.war /opt/payara/deployments
EXPOSE 4848 9009 8080 8181
```

I expected server log file mounted to host file from container but I get the 
error message below.

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/production/logs/server.log.lck

Comment: -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container. You should find the mount on the host at: /home/osboxes/Docker/var/log/card/credit-card

Comment: Btw, you might still get access denied errors on files created by the container if they are created as a uid/guid that isn't you with restricted permissions. Localhost root can always do anything with the files.

Comment: Help me to understand, when i am running image without -v option then i don't get any error message in log and server started successfully. When i use -v option then only i get AccessDeniedException in log and mount is happening with empty folder on the host side .

Comment: Does your user have write permission to the host folder before you mount there?

Comment: Try this: rerun the container with another, additional mount: -v ~/debugtest:/debugtest

Comment: Make sure that ~/debugtest exists on the host first.

Comment: Then from bash inside the container:  echo "Hello" > /debugtest/testfile.txt. You should be able to see it in ~/debugtest. Also, if you create a file from the host, it should show in the container: ls /debugtest.

Comment: Finally, the folder names don't have to be the same. I just picked names that were unlikely to already be on either system.

Comment: Btw, the reason you don't get errors when you don't add the volume is b/c the container is writing into /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/production/logs (assuming that this folder is correct) in its own filesystem and has permissions to do so. If you run bash or sh in the container, you should be able to see those files.